# Please recommend an easy xquery tool

Tags: xquery

I'm trying to grab some information from a private XML file used as DB schema, I'm thinking an XQuery command line tool could help. Would you please recommend one? Thanks. BTW, the implementations list is too long for me to pick...

Comment: Just had to say thanks for this question.  I know it's been closed because of SO's narrowminded, idiotic, unwavering quest for 'canonical answers'.  But thank god questions and answers like these are here until a better-than-SO website appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend downloading the trial of Oxygen XML editor and using it. Its not command based though... Not too sure what you are using as a development environment but if you need a good XQuery library i would recommend the Saxon libraries which i believe comes in many flavors. I know there is a .NET library.

Comment: Thank you, but I would prefer a cli based one. Because the output would very likely to be used for other script.

Answer (score 4):

here two gui versions...both open source

[kernow](http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/) uses saxon and has a bunch of features...  (EDIT:currently the newest version of kernow is trial and not free, unless you get the older versions.)

and then theres [qizx](http://www.axyana.com/qizx/) which comes with qizx studio, the gui isnt as good however it implements xquery 1.1 and xquery full text

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com).  It is free for non-commercial use and has more features than the free version of Saxon (in particular it is fully schema aware, and has a much more advanced optimizer).

Disclaimer: I am a developer for XQSharp and am therefore biased.